# exclude number from the Random picker list

Tags: java, android, game-development

i have a Random picker code that picks random number for ex from 1 to 6 ..
can u give me a method how to exclude the picked number from the list of random pick ..

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();

int  n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

like that for ex :
1.2.3.4.5.6
random pick=5
1.2.3.4.6
random pick=2
1.3.4.6 
.. etc
ty in advance guys

Comment: What have you tried? Just take the list {1,2,3,4,5,6} and shuffle it randomly, then read the values one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the numbers that have already been picked to an ArrayList and pick a number until the number is not contained in the list.

```
// list of numbers that I already picked
ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersPicked = new ArrayList<>();
// int to save the current random number
int myCurrentRandomNumber;

while(iNeedAnotherNumber){
    do {
        myCurrentRandomNumber = generateRandomNumber(a, b);
    //repeat this until the number is not in the list
    } while (randomNumbersPicked.contains(new Integer(myCurrentRandomNumber)));
    //here there is a unique random number, do what you will
    System.out.println("A new number has been picked: " + myCurrentRandomNumber);
    //add the number to the list so it wont be picked again
    randomNumbersPicked.add(new Integer(myCurrentRandomNumber));
}
```

Best Regards!
Dknacht.

Answer (score 0):

Put all valid numbers into an ArrayList and instead select a random index from the list. Then remove that number from the list and repeat.

My Java is a little rusty, so hopefully the code I write makes sense:

```
ArrayList<int> validOptions = /**/; // make your list with all initial options

int firstIndex = random.Next(validOptions.count());
int firstPick = validOptions.get(firstIndex);
validOptions.removeAt(firstIndex);

int secondIndex = random.Next(validOptions.count());
int secondPick = validOptions.get(secondIndex);
validOptions.removeAt(firstIndex);
```